# How to call a scanner recursively in this program?

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner

*This is my first post so i was unsure about formatting and didnt include the full program(i can if need be)*

I'm writing a program in which I want to use scanner in a method whose job is to receive a number, check its validity, and if its not valid, recurse and receive a new number.

When I run this, the scanner opens, takes the number, then gives me the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>           at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>           at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>           at Password.getGuess(Password.java:26)
>           at Password.checkPassword(Password.java:46)
>           at Password.getGuess(Password.java:35)
>           at Password.checkPassword(Password.java:46)
>           at Password.main(Password.java:7)

```
public static int getRange(){
    int range = (int) Math.pow(10, difficulty);
    return range;
}
public static int getGuess() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER PASSWORD_");
    int guess = in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    if (guess > (getRange() - 1) || guess < (getRange() / 10 )) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID_PASSWORD");
        return getGuess();
    } else {
        checkPassword();
        return guess;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion sounds like the exact *wrong* thing you want to do here...you want to simply retry  with a loop instead of recurse.

Comment: Never close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`.

Comment: I should add that I'm a high school senior with only a very fundamental knowledge of java. We just finished our recursion unit in AP ComSci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
boolean validInput = false;

while(!validInput)
{
    System.out.println("ENTER PASSWORD_");

    int guess = in.nextInt();

    if (guess > (getRange() - 1) || guess < (getRange() / 10 ))
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID_PASSWORD");
    }
    else
    {
        // this will cause your input loop to terminate
        validInput = true;
    }
}

checkPassword();
```

Comment: We haven't learned "while" yet but I'm assuming it acts as an if for one specific case and houses if/else s inside of it? Also, where would you close the scanner in that case?

Comment: `while` loops until an exit conditon is met -- you can put *anything* inside of it and it'll keep executing until your while condition holds true. Read the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). You don't close a Scanner wrapping `System.in` because closing the Scanner closes `System.in` too, potentially causing strange problems. In reality, once you know your Scanner is done taking input, it's not a big deal to close it. You just don't want to be opening and closing a Scanner wrapping `System.in` over and over in the same program.